# Active Admin custom filter. Filter date by day | month | year of a Date attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, meta-search

I have a Model with :birthday attribute and I want to filter out those dates by month specified in the form (ActiveAdmin's DSL :select).

This is an example of simple scope that extract only the month of birthday's date. Maybe can help:

```
scope :birthday_month, where('extract(month from birthday) = ?', Date.today.month)
```

Comment: What is the type of attribute :birthday?
Where are you stuck?

Comment: :birthday is a Date. I found the solution right now. I'm writing to post here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution:

On my Active Admin resource (app/admin/employees.rb) I put:

```
filter :month, :as => :select, :collection => (1..12)
```

And on my Model (app/models/employee.rb):

```
scope :month_eq, lambda{ |month| where("strftime('%m', birthday) + 0 = ?", month.to_i) }

search_methods :month_eq
```

This approach define '_eq' scope method (MetaSearch) and turn it avaible through `search_methods :month_eq` (MetaSearch too).

**NOTE:**
If you aren't using sqlite, maybe you'll desire to use `where('extract(month from birthday) = ?', month.to_i)` instead.

Comment: In the latest ActiveAdmin, MetaSearch has been replaced with Ransack so you'll need to use `ransacker` instead of `search_method`. Here's an [example](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/blob/master/spec/support/schema.rb#L18).

Comment: @onemanarmy can you kindly show how to implement this with ransacker? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solution for recent versions of Active Admin:

```
#app/admin/employees.rb
filter :month, :as => :select, :collection => (1..12)

#app/models/employee.rb
scope :month_eq, ->(month) { where('MONTH(birthday) = ?', month.to_i) } # for MySQL

def self.ransackable_scopes(_auth_object = nil)
  [:month_eq]
end
```